# Random URL Redirect On click php or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to redirect to a random URL from a list.

Example : 
I have 3 URLs: Google.com, Facebook.com, yahoo.com.

```
<a href="<?php $sites[array_rand($sites)] ?>">Visit here</a>
```

So whenever users click the link they will be redirected to one of the 3 URLs in the array. I have tried this code but not working as needed:

```
$sites = array(
'http://www.google.com/',
'http://www.facebook.com/',
'http://www.yahoo.com/'
);
die();
```

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon after `$sites = array(...);`

Comment: Also not clear if that href is legitimate or not. You haven't identified where the current redirect takes you

Answer (score 7):

The same functionality using javascript:

```
<a href='javascript:openUrl()'>Visit here</a>
<script>
var sites=['http://www.google.com/',
'http://www.msn.com/',
'http://www.yahoo.com/'
];

function openUrl(){
    var i = Math.round(Math.random()*(sites.length-1));
    window.location.href=sites[i];
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The first array entry is never chosen like this. Instead use: window.location.href = sites[Math.floor(Math.random()*sites.length)]; (no need vor var i)

Answer (score 1):

I got my code working.

```
<?php
$addresses = [
    'http://www.google.com',
    'http://www.facebook.com',
    'http://www.youtube.com'
];
$size = count($addresses);
$randomIndex = rand(0, $size - 1);
$randomUrl = $addresses[$randomIndex];
?>


<a href="<?php echo $randomUrl; ?>">random url</a>
```

If you have a better code, Please make a suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: I would recommend Pati's answer as it doesn't require refreshing the page for the URL to be different with each click. Since PHP is processed server-side, the URL isn't dynamic one it's sent to the client. Pati's JS answer dynamically changes the URL on the client.